# java regular expression optional characters

Tags: java, regex

I'm having problems getting my regular expression working.

The regular expression is:

```
([0-9]m)* ([0-9]f)*
```

A digit must come before "m" or "f" but "m" or "f" are optional. Example are:

```
1m 2f
1m
6f
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Should `2f 1m` be allowed? What about `2m 1m`? What about `11m`?

Comment: When you say "m" or "f" are optional, is `1` ok by itself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `*` means match the previous token 0 or more times, which doesn't look like what you want.

These should help you to build the regular expression you need:

- `?` to mean 0 or 1 matches.
- `|` for alternation.
- `(?:...)` for a non-capturing group.
- `^` and `$` to anchor at the start and end of the string.

Knowing that, I imagine that you can probably find a solution by yourself, but for the sake of completion, I'll show one possible solution.

---

Your question isn't very clear so I'm just going to assume that you want the following to match:

```
1m 2f
1m
6f 
0m
```

and that you want the following to fail to match:

```
1
m    
11m
1m 1m
2f 3m
1m  2f
"1m 2f"
```

If those assumptions are incorrect, then please make your question more clear.

With those assumptions, try this:

```
^[0-9]m(?: [0-9]f)?$|^[0-9]f$
```

If you also want `2f 3m` to match then use this:

```
^[0-9]m(?: [0-9]f)?$|^[0-9]f(?: [0-9]m)?$
```